# Calculating the probability of P(A-(B-C))

Tags: probability-theory

Could you help me calculate the probability of P(A-(B-C)).
I know that P(A-B) = 0.2 , P(A∩B) = 0.3 and P(A∩B∩C) = 0.25.

What I have been able to figure out so far and believe is correct:

P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A∩B) (=) 0.2 = P(A) - 0.3 (=) P(A) = 0.5

P(A-(B-C)) = P(A∩($\overline{B-C}$)) = P(A∩$\overline{B∩\overline{C}}$) = P(A∩$\overline{B}$∪C)

I know that I have to use the value of P(A∩B∩C) but I can't see a way to.

Comment: could you clarify the notation? 'p(a-b)'

Comment: @gebra I guess the user means the set difference.

Comment: i believe the minus sign represents that same as except. So you could say that it is A except B

Comment: i believe this notation could also mean P(A\B)

Comment: oh, i would write that as P(A|B')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A-(B-C)=A\cap (B-C)^C = A\cap ((B\cap C^C)^C)=A\cap (B^C \cup C)= (A\cap B^C)\cup (A \cap C)$

Now $(A\cap B^C)=A-B$, and you know the probability of this.

$(A\cap C)= (A\cap C)\cap (B\cup B^C) = (A\cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap B^C \cap C)$. But notice $(A \cap B^C \cap C) \subseteq A\cap B^C=A-B$, while $(A\cap B \cap C)$ is disjoint from $A \cap B^C=A-B$. That is, $(A \cap C)$ overlaps with $(A-B)$ precisely in the set $(A\cap B^C \cap C)$.

Thus $A-(B-C)=(A \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap C) = (A-B) \cup (A\cap B \cap C)$, and these two sets are disjoint. Drawing a venn diagram of sets will make this obvious; the set manipulations obscure what is really going on. You can see that the purple region is the disjoint union of the orange/yellow region and the green region.

[image]

Comment: orange region is shaded wrong probably

Comment: Oops thanks, I'll see if I can fix it.